# How to get Tumblr trending through Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

This was asked but never ever answered. I'm using Ruby and I want to get the URLs/details of posts from the trending page "https://www.tumblr.com/explore/trending"

Answer (score 0):

There is a ruby gem for the tumbler API

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client

and you can find the Tumblr posts API documentation [here](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts)

but I had a quick look and couldn't find a endpoint to fetch posts from trending page but have a look and maybe you can find a way to get it from there or if all else fails, you can even try some simple web-scraping.

Web Scraping means going through a web page to fetch contents that you need, there should be examples on how to do it in ruby,

https://morph.io/ seems like a good one but I haven't tried it out so I'm not sure how easy is it to use.

These are some tutorials to help you get started using `nokogiri`

https://www.distilled.net/resources/web-scraping-with-ruby-and-nokogiri-for-beginners/
https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/web-scraping-using-ruby

Comment: When you say "simple webscraping" what do you mean by that? Wheres a good place to start?